# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ converge (absolutely)?

I've already tried the Ratio test and the Limit comparison test, but the series failed both...

Comment: Have you (carefully) tried a comparison with the series $\sum 1/n$?

Comment: I prefer Comparison, but Limit Comparison (with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$) works OK.

Comment: Since you have the word "absolute" in the question, are you sure that the series does not have a factor $(-1)^n$ in it?

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \geq \dfrac1{n+1}$$ and recall that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n+1}$$ diverges.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\ge\frac1{\sqrt2\,n}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Or you can apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Here, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, then your series converges if and only if $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$ converges.

But, $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\ln|\sqrt{x^2+1}+x|\vert_0^M=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\ln|\sqrt{M^2+1}+M|=\infty$, it diverges.